# Render turning black after completion

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am trying to follow along tutorials by [Blender Guru](https://www.youtube.com/c/BlenderGuruOfficial). When I try rendering my model, everything seems to work fine right until the completion where the render goes black. I've no clue as to why this is happening because every tutorial I refer to seems to get it to work without any problems.

This only happens when I'm running with `Cycles` as my rendering engine. I have attached relevant screenshots below as well as a link to my model. I've googled about the error but none of the fixes mentioned work. Please help me out, thanks!

[image: When rendering is taking place]

[image: When rendering completes]

As you can see, the rendering works fine until just before completion (frame 1680/2048 in image).

Some of the many things I've tried so far:

- Set exposure to 1.0 (it was this by default)
- Check if all objects are set to be rendered
- Try restarting (because apparently someone else had a RAM issue and doing so fixed it)
- Try rendering a simple default cube. Still fails...
- Link the image option from `Render View` node to image option in `Composite` node in the Compositing tab
- Delete and add a new camera (because this fixed it for someone else)
- Other parameter changes that seem to do nothing

[Link to model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D7DQHv-rJmjRq1kaiO4j1Mfe1YHNz5uH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: i just rendered it - and it works [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZtZN.jpg, so i can just assume that you might have a problem with your hardware/graphics card?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your response! I believe it might be a problem with some settings in my model that are causing issues on my end. I have managed to successfully render models available online using the `Cycles` render engine and everything seems to work perfectly except my own model. If someone can figure out why, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: If this would have been settings on your model - I wouldn’t be able to render it. So I think that’s not a possible reason.

Comment: Not just the model, but the .blend file as well. If there was an issue in how you set up your rendering or if your file was corrupted, we should be able to reproduce the issue or at least have "some"  issue. But [everything's fine here](https://i.imgur.com/hS2bOXb.jpeg). And you wouldn't have the issue with the default cube either. So this really sound like a system issue. Try reinstalling your graphics driver and Blender, also make sure you meet [Blender's requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I do meet the requirements. It most likely is an issue with my graphics drivers and I'll try working on diagnosing that.

Comment: If you can't get it working with updated drivers or using the latest stable Blender release, try maybe the [latest daily build](https://builder.blender.org/download/daily/). If even that doesn't work, go to the menu Help → Report a bug and follow the bug report guidelines. Hopefully it's a bug the devs can solve or an issue they know how you can fix.